# Save color and strikethrough text with sharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, listview, colors, sharedpreferences

I have custom adapter and an `ArrayList<String>` called `groceries` containing whatever user puts there.

This is my method saving the listView whenever the user puts something there or deletes:

```
public void saveGroceriesList() {
    sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("com.me.application", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet(groceries);
    sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("Groceries", set).apply();
}
```

And here I set text strikethrough and change color onClick for listView:

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            list_content = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_content);

            if (!isChecked){

                isChecked = true;
                list_content.setPaintFlags(list_content.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                list_content.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#a7a7a7"));
                saveGroceriesList();

            } else {

                isChecked = false;
                list_content.setPaintFlags(list_content.getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
                list_content.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                saveGroceriesList();

            }

        }
    });
```

where `list_content` is my TextView for listView. The problem is, that the `saveGroceriesList();` method wont save the color. 
How can I save the color and strikethrough text with sharedPreferences?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see where are you adding color values into the Set, I think it is that problem

Comment: How would I add them to set if I have seperate TextView?

Comment: do you want to get allData from listview and save them?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution, by far IMHO, is to use a better data storage model. For example, you could use a SQLite database, with columns for the various properties (name, checked). Or, you could store your data in a JSON file, or an XML file, or a CSV file, or some other form of simple file.

If, for whatever reason, you are sure that you want to use `SharedPreferences`, you could:

- Create a `GroceryItem` class that knows the name and checked state information
- Hold an `ArrayList<GroceryItem>` that is your in-memory representation of your data model
- Use Gson, Jackson, or some other JSON parser to convert the `ArrayList<GroceryItem>` to and from a `String` representation
- Save the `String` in `SharedPreferences`

Comment: I haven't worked with SQLite databases, but I will take your answer in account and try thath. Thanks!